# How to Specify Out Unit to Be in Decimal Degree in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using a Map service on ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 which is in this format

```
Spatial Reference: 102100  (3857) 
Single Fused Map Cache: false 
Initial Extent:
XMin: -9819759.37726215
YMin: 5128008.078704429
XMax: -9809084.764440382
YMax: 5132626.115644935
Spatial Reference: 102100  (3857)
Full Extent:
XMin: -9819004.6505
YMin: 5125535.589900002
XMax: -9809349.0802
YMax: 5131992.668099999
Spatial Reference: 102100  (3857)

Units: esriMeters
```

Now when I query the service it returns the data in **Meter** format which I can not display back them on the map as new graphics. Can you please let me know how I can change the service configuration or **OutUnit** in ArcGIS JavaScript API to be in **Decimal Degree**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Output Spatial Reference` to `4326`

Comment: Thanks for reply GavinR, I change the out spatial to 4326 and as you can see from below I am getting geometry in wkid:4236 but I am getting the X and Y in Meter not in decimal degree! 
{OBJECTID: 1100}
geometry:
spatialReference:{wkid: 4326}
type:"point"
x:-9814834.6714
y:5130507.876800001